# Line breaks with WCF, JSON and a non-Windows client

Tags: c#, android, json, wcf, newline

I have a .NET WCF service using `WebMessageFormat.Json` as both its `ResponseFormat` and its `RequestFormat`. The service runs on a Windows server, the client is an Android tablet.

As it turns out, strings sent from the client to the server contain `LF` linebreaks ("\n") instead of `CRLF`("\r\n"). Since Android is Linux-based, this is not surprising. However, the data is stored in a Windows database and read by Windows clients, so I need `CRLF` line breaks.

**Is there a more elegant way to solve this issue than to manually `s = s.Replace("\n", "\r\n");` every string received via WCF?** Since WCF has so many options and features, I figured that there might be some hidden `AutoTranslateNewlines` option that I have missed...

---

Additional information: My service is declared roughly like this:

```
[OperationContract()]
[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "MyService?UserId={myUserId}")]
public Reply MyService(String myUserId, Request someRequest) { ... }
```

where `Request` is a custom class with a few `String` fields, some of which can contain multiple lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you are using

```
s = s.Replace("\n","\r\n");
```

But an issue could arise where you have *some* `"\r\n"` sequences in your string.  These would become `"\r\r\n"`, which would be an issue.  To solve this problem, simply do the following instead.

```
s = s.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
s = s.Replace("\r", "\n");
s = s.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
```

which should handle all situations, though perhaps not the most performant.  For better performance, perhaps you can use a regular expression.